# I have problem with gnome3

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I have a problem  with this code in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

It's not working

Look at this error

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

What should i do to install gnome3?

---

Thank you for that link.

I typed this code in terminal:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

And this:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

And my previous problem has solved.

But when I type this in terminal again:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

It's doesn't work again!

Look at this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree    
Reading state information... Done
gnome-shell is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 219 not upgraded.
```

How can I use gnome3 interface?

Comment: The package `gnome-shell` is already installed on your system. Also, you have a lot of updates that need to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing gnome 3, have you logged out of the system?

Gnome-Shell isn't an application you just load up, it's a desktop environment.

I suggest that you log out and at the login screen click the Ubuntu symbol and choose the Gnome 3 option. You should then see Gnome Shell in all its glory.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the message it gave you:

```
gnome-shell is already the newest version.
```

That means you already have the latest `gnome-shell` installed on your system.

Also notice:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 219 not upgraded.
```

You have 219 updates that need to be performed. You can either use the update-manager or run

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go to ubuntu software center and install Gnome3 desktop environment there. It may be listed as gnome desktop environment. Or else you can install it from terminal
as **[this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-install-gnome-38-on-ubuntu/)** tutorial explains .